# How do I play Call of Duty with a mouse and keyboard on a PS3?

Tags: ps3, keyboard, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

How could I play Call of Duty on PS3 with a keyboard and mouse?
Give me all the information you have, please.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, none of the CoD games support MKB on PS3. However, you can buy a (nowadays) cheap MKB-to-PS3 adapter from places like Amazon.

**Do be warned**: using MKB in multiplayer console shooters, unless officially supported (like in CSGO for PS3/X360 or MW2019 for PS4/XONE), is controversial/frowned upon.